# SQL Server Query using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble writing a query that will select all Skills, joining the Employee and Competency records, but only return one skill per employee, their newest Skill.  Using this sample dataset

```
Skills
======
id   employee_id   competency_id   created
1    1             1               Jan 1
2    2             2               Jan 1
3    1             2               Jan 3

Employees
===========
id   first_name   last_name
1    Mike         Jones
2    Steve        Smith


Competencies
============
id   title
1    Problem Solving
2    Compassion
```

I would like to retrieve the following data

```
Skill.id   Skill.employee_id   Skill.competency_id   Skill.created   Employee.id   Employee.first_name   Employee.last_name   Competency.id   Competency.title
2          2                   2                     Jan 1           2             Steve                 Smith                2               Compassion
3          1                   2                     Jan 3           1             Mike                  Jones                2               Compassion
```

I was able to select the employee_id and max created  using

```
SELECT MAX(created) as created, employee_id  FROM skills GROUP BY employee_id
```

But when I start to add more fields in the select statement or add in a join I get the 'Column 'xyz' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' error.

Any help is appreciated and I don't have to use GROUP BY, it's just what I'm familiar with.

Comment: Add the additional columns to the group by clause?

Comment: When I add additional columns to the group by, I don't get the results I want. The employee_ids end up showing multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you were getting is because SQL Server requires any item in the `SELECT` list to be included in the `GROUP BY` if there is an aggregate function being used.

The problem with that is you might have unique values in some columns which can throw off the result.  So you will want to rewrite the query to use one of the following:

You can use a subquery to get this result. This gets the `max(created)` in a subquery and then you use that result to get the correct employee record:

```
select s.id SkillId,
  s.employee_id,
  s.competency_id,
  s.created,
  e.id employee,
  e.first_name,
  e.last_name,
  c.id competency,
  c.title
from Employees e
left join Skills s
  on e.id = s.employee_id
inner join
(
  SELECT MAX(created) as created, employee_id  
  FROM skills 
  GROUP BY employee_id
) s1
  on s.employee_id = s1.employee_id
  and s.created = s1.created
left join Competencies c
  on s.competency_id  = c.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2259/12)

Or another way to do this is to use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from
(
  select s.id SkillId,
    s.employee_id,
    s.competency_id,
    s.created,
    e.id employee,
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    c.id competency,
    c.title,
    row_number() over(partition by s.employee_id 
                      order by s.created desc) rn
  from Employees e
  left join Skills s
    on e.id = s.employee_id
  left join Competencies c
    on s.competency_id  = c.id
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2259/13)

Answer (score 1):

For every non-aggregated column you add to your `SELECT` statement you need to update your `GROUP BY` to include it.

This [article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-in-sql-server) may help you understand why.

Comment: Thanks for the article. It sounds like I need to use a derived table to get the results I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH
MAX_SKILL_created AS
(
    SELECT
        MAX(skills.created) as created,
        skills.employee_id
    FROM
        skills
    GROUP BY
        skills.employee_id
),
MAX_SKILL_id AS
(
    SELECT
        MAX(skills.id) as id,
        skills.employee_id
    FROM
        skills
        INNER JOIN MAX_SKILL_created
            ON MAX_SKILL_created.employee_id = skills.employee_id
            AND MAX_SKILL_created.created = skills.created
    GROUP BY
        skills.employee_id
)
SELECT
    * -- type all your columns here
FROM
    employees
    INNER JOIN MAX_SKILL_id
        ON MAX_SKILL_id.employee_id = employees.employee_id
    INNER JOIN skills
        ON skills.id = MAX_SKILL_id.id
    INNER JOIN competencies
        ON competencies.id = skills.competency_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server than you can use OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT *
FROM employees E
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM skills
    WHERE employee_id = E.id
    ORDER BY created DESC
) S
INNER JOIN competencies C
    ON C.id = S.competency_id
```